# Ajaxifications of panels in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am having two panels consisting two gridviews and having some filters separate for both the panels right now on applying any dropdown filter is reloading the whole page as it is doing a full postback i want to make both the panels ajaxified so that on applying filters in one panel will refresh that panel only what approach should i take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you seen the ?

this should do exactly what you want. Just wrap both panels in an UpdatePanel.

You will also need to add a ScriptManager to the page.

N

Comment: i have to wrap them inside one update panel or two update panels

Comment: You could do it in one or two. It depends on how much data is inside the update panel, if its a whole page in the update panel then this would take longer to update than just a part of the page.

Comment: You can use ajax calls but you will have to return the HTML that is going to be placed in the panel that needs to be updated with the content. Im not sure if there is a method on the gridview to return the HTML that is to be rendered so you might have to return the HTML for the full table etc yourself. You could use an update panel and have a hidden button on the page that updates the content that you could call from a javascript method but this would still involve the  use of update panels. Other people may have other suggestions